# sudoers NOPASSWD tag doesn't seem to work

Tags: fedora, sudo

I'm working on adjusting a script I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521620/prevent-machine-from-sleeping-when-ssh-connections-are-on/1226566#1226566) for my own purposes.

In essence, the script checks some conditions, and then runs one of two commands using sudo. The command executes as the user `cas`.

Since the script won't run interactively, I want to ensure that the sudo commands in there go through without a password prompt. So, I added the following lines to my sudoers file:

```
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target
```

From my understanding of how the sudoers file works, this means that all users are allowed to execute the commands `/usr/bin/systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target` and `/usr/bin/systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target` without a password prompt.

Instead, the password prompt still appears:

> cas-desktop :: ~ » sudo /usr/bin/systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target
> [sudo] password for cas:
> sudo: a password is required

I've also tried without sudo:

> cas-desktop :: ~ » /usr/bin/systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target
> ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ====
> Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
> Authenticating as: Cas (cas)
> Password:

I'm not sure what else to do to make this work, so if you have an idea please do let me know.

Comment: @ChrisDavies Thanks, I am indeed in the wheel group and thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768741/38945) I learned that the order in which you are mentioned matters. I incorrectly assumed that the most specific entry would take precedence. But yes, `which systemctl` returns `/usr/bin/systemctl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run `sudo -l` and see if you have other allowed `sudo` command lines defined for your user. This will display *all* applicable sudoers configuration lines, both from the main configuration and from any included `/etc/sudoers.d/*` files, if you have any.

Ordering is important: the *last* line that can match your command will be honored. If that line is a general `(ALL : ALL) ALL` line without the `NOPASSWD:` tag, you *will* be asked for a password. In that case, move your `NOPASSWD:`-tagged lines to a later position in the `sudoers` file.

If the last line of the sudoers file is `@includedir /etc/sudoers.d`, consider moving your sudo configuration lines into a separate file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`. Note that any filenames in that directory that either end in `~` or contain a `.` character *will be ignored*.

---

Alternatively, to allow it without `sudo`, you would need to write a `polkit` rule file, e.g. `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/01-local-sleep-suspend.rules`:

```
// -*- mode: js2 -*-
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
         (action.lookup("unit") == "sleep.target" ||
          action.lookup("unit") == "suspend.target") &&
        subject.user == "cas") {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed my issue was that I incorrectly assumed that a more specific (i.e mentioning a specific command instead of just `ALL`) would take precendence, but now I've learned that this is not the case. I'll also check out that polkit approach :)